# Android device not recognized in several programs (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, android, visual-studio, adb

I have a problem getting my Android device to work in Visual Studio for Debugging.

I almost tried everything I could find in the last days:

- enable USB Debugging
- Install ADB drivers
- Change Protocols
- Different cables
- Different USB Ports
- and so on...

The strange thing is: It is recognized by the windows device manager and ADB Interface is also shown as working properly. I can access the data via explorer without any problems. My phone wont appear in any software that should support it (Visual Studio, Kies, Smart Switch, ...). I can't find any solution for this problem.

Comment: Which visual studio are you using? Also, did you grant authorisation for USB debugging in your phone?

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. And yes I enabled USB debugging. That was the first thing I did. Btw it works on my home Computer but not on Computer at work.